# How to recover an interface through crosscast

Tags: c++, interface, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

First base class

```
class Io_obj
{
public:
    virtual Io_obj* clone() const=0;
    virtual ~Io_obj(){}
};
```

First derived class

```
template<typename T>
class Io : public Io_obj,T
{
public:
    Io(){}
    Io(string& s){cout << s << '\n';}
    Io* clone() const override {return new Io{*this};}
    static Io* new_io(string& s){return new Io{s};}
};
```

Second base class

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual void draw() const=0;
    virtual ~Shape(){}
};
```

Second derived classes

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle(){}
    Circle(string& s){cout << s << '\n';}
    void draw() const override{cout << "draw circle\n";}
};

class Triangle : public Shape
{
public:
    Triangle(){}
    Triangle(string& s){cout << s << '\n';}
    void draw() const override {cout << "draw triangle";}
};
```

main functions

```
using io_circle = Io<Circle>;
using io_triangle = Io<Triangle>;
using Pf = function<Io_obj*(string&)>;

map<string,Pf> io_map{{"circle",&io_circle::new_io},{"triangle",&io_triangle::new_io}};

Io_obj* get_obj(string& s){
    if(auto f=io_map[s]) return f(s);
    throw runtime_error{"error: wrong type"};
}

int main(){
    vector<string> vs{"circle","triangle","square"};
    for(auto x:vs){
        unique_ptr<Io_obj> my_obj{get_obj(x)};

        if(auto sp=dynamic_cast<Shape*>(my_obj.get())){
            sp->draw();
        }else{
            throw runtime_error{"error: bad cast"};
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Dynamic cast failed. It seems that the object created by `unique_ptr<Io_obj> my_obj{get_obj(x)}` is of type `Io_obj`, which has no member function `draw()`. How to make it work?

Code from Bjarne Stroustrup: the C++ programming language Ch22.2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, change:

```
template<typename T>
class Io : public Io_obj, T
```

to:

```
template<typename T>
class Io : public Io_obj, public T
```

Access specifiers must be written separately for each base type. In your case, second derivation was `private`, as this is the default mode.

`dynamic_cast<>` converts `Io<T>` to `T`, if they are connected with *is-a* relation, which is created by public inheritation. In case of private, `dynamic_cast<>` will not work, because `Io<T>` *is not* `T` (private inheritance creates relation called *"implemented in terms of"*).

Test: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/130c7768fb5b501d

Of course this code will also throw an `std::runtime_error`, as you have not registered "factory" for `square` type, but I guess you already know this :)

Some reference, perhaps (**18.5.2** - `dynamic_cast<T>(v)`):

> Otherwise, a run-time check is applied to see if the object pointed or
>   referred to by `v` can be converted to the type pointed or referred to
>   by `T`.
>
> The run-time check logically executes as follows:
>
> If, in the most derived object pointed (referred) to by `v`, v points
>   (refers) to a **public** base class subobject of a `T` object, and if
>   only one object of type `T` is derived from the sub-object pointed
>   (referred) to by `v`, the result is a pointer (an lvalue referring) to
>   that `T` object.
>
> Otherwise, if `v` points (refers) to a **public** base class
>   sub-object of the most derived object, and the type of the most
>   derived object has a base class, of type `T`, that is unambiguous and
>   **public**, the result is a pointer (an lvalue referring) to the `T` sub-object of the most derived object.
>
> Otherwise, the run-time check fails.
>
> The value of a failed cast to pointer type is the null pointer value
>   of the required result type. A failed cast to reference type throws
>   `bad_cast`.

Comment: `dynamic_cast<>` converts `Io<T>` to `T`. If I understand correctly, during this process `Circle` becomes the public base of `Io`. Therefore `Io` inherits `Circle`'s member function `draw()`. As `draw()` is declared as `virtual` in `Circle`'s public base `Shape`, the call of `sp->draw()` can finally be processed by the compiler.

Comment: @MiloLu Yes, that's it. Although it is not processed by the compiler. Virtual functions (I don't take any optimizations into account) are generally processed at runtime to determine what is the actual type of the object (and which virtual function should be called).

Comment: I tried a different approach: placing `T` as a member instead of the public base, and post the question again. Maybe you can have some suggestions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614524/how-to-cast-an-objx-to-an-x?noredirect=1#comment55004110_33614524